# Deleting an object and it's vars in C++

Tags: c++

I have a class and I want to delete it. Inside the class is a variety of vars, strings, vectors etc.

When I call from another class:

```
delete myClass;
```

And when I create a new myClass, the vars seem to still be there.

Do I need to manually delete each var inside:

```
myClass::~myClass()
{
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `I have a class and I want to delete it` Do you mean an object of class `myClass`? Also, are those strings, vectors, etc. created with `new`? If so you have to explicitly delete them in `~myclass()` in order to free their memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any member of an object will be destroyed when that object is destroyed. For example:

```
struct A
{
  int x;
  char y;
  float* z;
};

void foo()
{
  A* ap = new A{5, 6};
  ap->z = new float(13.37f); // This will be leaked
  delete ap;
  // You may find that the following still works:
  // std::cout << ap.x << std::endl;
}
```

After `delete ap`, the object pointed to by `ap` is destroyed. All of its members are destroyed: `x`, `y`, and `z` are now gone. However, note that `z` is only a pointer. The pointer will be destroyed, but not the `float` object that it is pointing at. You would need to make sure you `delete ap->z` too. The easy way to tell is that we have two `new`s but only one `delete` - this is a pretty good sign that there is a memory leak. This code will leak the dynamically allocated `float`.

As noted in the code comment above, you may find that attempting to access the members of the object still works just fine and you even get the right value. However, it's not okay. If you try to access any part of an object that has been `delete`d, you get *undefined behaviour*. This means anything can happen, including appearing to work fine. Any C++ that invokes undefined behaviour is completely unreliable and could destroy the universe.

Comment: This is one of my vars that does not get destroyed:

Comment: QVariantList recordingsData;

Comment: Any idea why, when I use delete on teh object?

Comment: @user1013512 See my last paragraph. Just added it.

Comment: @MatsPetersson Keep reading. :D I'll stick a comment in so it's clearer.

Answer (score 0):

If they are pointers to class instances which are meant to be unique to your first instance, you will have to delete them. Otherwise, they will be deleted with their container.